# How to put Input and Icon in the same line Materialize?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I have this HTML, need to show the input and the icon in the same line...

```html
 <input type="search" ng-model="q" 
        placeholder="Pesquise algo! :)" 
        aria-label="filter docs"/>
 <i class="material-icons">search</i>
```

And i got this [two lines elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFlfk.jpg)

need to look like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOcSF.jpg) in single line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
      <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```